# Conditionally import xml resource in Spring integration

Tags: java, xml, spring-integration

I have an xml file that imports another xml file using a property. That other file depends on said property:

```
<import resource="internaltracking-http-workflow-${http.flow:enabled}.xml"/>
```

And the file loaded will either be `internaltracking-http-workflow-enabled.xml` or `internaltracking-http-workflow-disabled.xml`.

Ideally, I would like to delete the second file, as it is just an empty file. Is there a way to import the resource conditionally using my `http.flow` condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider to use [Spring Profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-definition-profiles)

With that you should do something like this:

Where that `<import>` will be included only if `http.flow` profile is active.

Comment: I had seen the profiles while searching, but `http.flow` is just a property in a `.properties` file. Not sure how to link the two, as I'm not very confident with Spring.

Comment: Yeah... Why do we write RFTM? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-definition-profiles-enable